# Scrapy Xpath cannot find content in web page

Tags: xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I tried to crawl this site: https://www.kbb.com/compare-cars/results/?vehicleids=1 and get some info from this page.
I used scrapy shell to test my xpath:

scrapy shell https://www.kbb.com/compare-cars/results/?vehicleids=1

And I tried to use the following xpath to get the div which does exist in the html but just cannot be fetched by my scrapy, it just returned an empty list for me.

response.xpath('//div[@id="vehicleCardsContainer"]')

Comment: Going to the site and using the Devtools to inspect the page, I do not have any hits on the page for the xpath. Are you sure, that the xpath is correct -> maybe it is a TYPO: "VECHICLE"? Which info do you want to scrape?

Comment: @Shushiro Sorry it was a typo in my question, I actually tried to query response.xpath('//div[@id="vehicleCardsContainer"]').
This certain div shows up in Devtools, but when I triedto query it with Xpath in scrapy, it didn't return anything.